# problema con sesiones no puedo aumentar la cantidad de productos de mi carrito como lo hago?

Tags: php, session

Este es el codigo que agrege para sumar lo que hay en la sesion pero no funciona solo se coloca
el valor que se envia por url no se suma

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST["btnagregar"])) {
        $producto = $_REQUEST["txtproducto"];
        $cantidad = $_REQUEST["cant"];
        $precio = $_REQUEST["txtprecio"];

        
        if (isset($_SESSION["carrito"])) {
            
        
             foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $pindice => $arr) {
                if ($producto == $pindice) {
                    $totalcantidad =  $_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['cantidad'] + $cantidad;
                    $_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['cantidad'] = $totalcantidad;
                }else{

                    $_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['cantidad'] = $cantidad;
                    $_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['precio'] = $precio;
                }    
            }
        }else{
            
                $_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['cantidad'] = $cantidad;
                $_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['precio'] = $precio;
        }
        
 
 echo "<pre>";
        echo print_r($_SESSION, true);
 echo "</pre>";
        echo "<script>alert('Producto $producto agregado con exito al carrito de compras'); 
 </script>";

    }
 ?>
```

Este codigo es para mostrar los productos agregados en esta parte no tengo problema solo hay que terminar algunas cosas que hasta ahorita no he hecho por que me estanque en esta duda

```
<?php
session_start();
//session_destroy();

$total = 0;

echo "<h3>Carrito de compras</h3>";
if (isset($_SESSION["carrito"])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $indice => $arreglo) {
        echo "<hr>Producto: <strong>". $indice. "</strong><br>";
        $total+= $arreglo["cantidad"] * $arreglo["precio"];
        foreach ($arreglo as $key => $value) {
            echo $key . ": " .$value. "<br>";
        }
    }

    echo "<h3>El total de la compra es de: $ $total</h3>";

    echo "<br><br><a href='carrito_compras.php'>Regresar</a>";
}else{

    echo "<script>alert('El carrito esta vacio');</script>";


    header("location:carrito_compras.php");
}


    echo "<a href=''>vaciarcarrito</a>";
?>
```

La cuestion es porque en ves de aumentar la cantidad de productos si agrego 4 y habia 3 no se suma si no que se establece el ultimo numero que seria el 4

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona exactamente?

Comment: En el primer script de php recibe los datos del producto y luego los asigna a la session pero al asignarlos yo quiero aumentar la cantidad del producto porque cuando intento aumentar la cantidad, cuando doy clic en agregar se quita lo que ya tenia en la sesion por ejemplo agrego 3 chicles y si se agregan a la sesion pero si quiero agregar otros dos chicles osea el mismo producto lo que hace es tomar ese ultimo numero osea dos y no se suma yo intente hacer eso que ves en el primer script pero no fuccnciono

Comment: Pero hay varios scripts en tu pregunta, ¿dónde es el problema exactamente?

Comment: en el primero que coloque donde esta el request basicamente ahi esta el problema el otro solo lo puse de complemento

Comment: No entiendo por qué usas un `foreach` ahí ¿? ¿Por qué no verificas si ese producto existe, sumando la cantidad en ese caso o creando el producto en la variable de sesión en caso de no existir?

Comment: Lo uso para eso recorro la matriz con el foreach para despues con  un if tomar el nombre del producto que entro por request y compararlo con el que esta en la matriz de sesion si es igual que sume la cantidad sino que proceda a a gregarlo a la matriz sesion

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas recorrer cada vez el carrito completo para verificar el nuevo producto o para actualizar la cantidad. Puedes buscar por la clave (que sería en este caso lo que haya en la variable `$producto`), para verificar si ese producto ya existe, en cuyo caso aumentarías la cantidad, y si no existe, los creas y le asignas cantidad y precio.

Veamos un ejemplo. He creado una función `addProduct()` para que quede más claro. Dado que no tengo contexto de sesiones ni de `$_REQUEST` he creado esos elementos *hardcode*.

Esta es la función:

```
function addProduct($producto,$cantidad,$precio) {
    if (isset($_SESSION["carrito"][$producto])) {
        #Si el producto existe se aumenta la cantidad
        $_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['cantidad']=$_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['cantidad']+$cantidad;
    }else{
        #Si no existe se crea con la cantidad y el precio
        $_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['cantidad'] = $cantidad;
        $_SESSION["carrito"][$producto]['precio'] = $precio;
    }
}
```

Ahora hagamos varias pruebas:

```
#Valores hardcode para prueba        
$_SESSION=array();

$producto = "unProducto"; //$_REQUEST["txtproducto"];
$cantidad = 2; //$_REQUEST["cant"];
$precio = 50; //$_REQUEST["txtprecio"];

addProduct($producto,$cantidad,$precio);
echo "Aquí ocurre el else, se crea 'unProducto':\n";
var_dump($_SESSION);

echo "\nAquí ocurre el if y se suma 2+5 en 'unProducto':\n";
addProduct("unProducto",5,50);
var_dump($_SESSION);

echo "\nAquí ocurre el else, se crea 'otroProducto':\n";
addProduct("otroProducto",3,20);
var_dump($_SESSION);

echo "\nAquí ocurre el if, se suma 3+1 en 'otroProducto':\n";
addProduct("otroProducto",1,20);
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

**Resultado de las pruebas:**

```
Aquí ocurre el else, se crea 'unProducto':
array(1) {
  ["carrito"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["unProducto"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["cantidad"]=>
      int(2)
      ["precio"]=>
      int(50)
    }
  }
}

Aquí ocurre el if y se suma 2+5 en 'unProducto':
array(1) {
  ["carrito"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["unProducto"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["cantidad"]=>
      int(7)
      ["precio"]=>
      int(50)
    }
  }
}

Aquí ocurre el else, se crea 'otroProducto':
array(1) {
  ["carrito"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["unProducto"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["cantidad"]=>
      int(7)
      ["precio"]=>
      int(50)
    }
    ["otroProducto"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["cantidad"]=>
      int(3)
      ["precio"]=>
      int(20)
    }
  }
}

Aquí ocurre el if, se suma 3+1 en 'otroProducto':
array(1) {
  ["carrito"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["unProducto"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["cantidad"]=>
      int(7)
      ["precio"]=>
      int(50)
    }
    ["otroProducto"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["cantidad"]=>
      int(4)
      ["precio"]=>
      int(20)
    }
  }
}
```